# Triggering javascript from Python Flask WTForms field

Tags: javascript, flask-wtforms

I have a Flask form (via WTForms) in my website, and am trying to enable or disable other fields in my form based on whether a user has selected or de-selected a checkbox (and do this without having to refresh the page) however, my attempts to achieve this by using the onchange or onclick event in the HTML hasn't worked. My field is defined below (label and field)

```
<div class="form-group row">
  {{ form.task_submit_sms.label(class_="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label") }}
  <div class="col-sm-1">
      {{ form.task_submit_sms(class_="custom-control custom-checkbox" onclick="enableSMSFields()") }}
  </div>
```

I have tried both *onclick* and *onchange*. and get the following error:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got
>   'onclick'

Not sure if it's relevant, but here's my JavaScript:

```
<script>
  // Lock SMS fields unless required
  function enableSMSFields()
  {
    if (document.getElementById('task_submit_sms').checked == true)
    {
      document.getElementById('task_sms_text').removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById('task_sms_text').setAttribute('disabled','disabled')
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a function inside the curly brackets, which you are passing arguments separated by commas (that is what the error is saying to you):

```
{{ form.task_submit_sms(class_="custom-control custom-checkbox" onclick="enableSMSFields()") }}
```

Have you tried inserting the comma separator?

```
{{ form.task_submit_sms(class_="custom-control custom-checkbox", onclick="enableSMSFields()") }}
```